# antdesign version 1.x on react 15

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to test antdesign version 1.x stable on react 15/16 but there is very strange error appears.

```
import React from 'react15';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'antd-1x';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';  // or 'antd/dist/antd.less'



ReactDOM.render(
    <div>test
        <Button type="ghost">sd</Button>
    </div>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

> antd.js?149b:15180 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'number')
> at Object.eval (antd.js?149b:15180)
> at **webpack_require** (antd.js?149b:36)
> at webpackContext (antd.js?149b:13318)
> at eval (antd.js?149b:24612)
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Object.eval (antd.js?149b:24611)
> at **webpack_require** (antd.js?149b:36)
> at Object.eval (antd.js?149b:86)
> at **webpack_require** (antd.js?149b:36)
> at eval (antd.js?149b:56)

```
  offsetTop: _react2["default"].PropTypes.number,
```

Comment: You have to use the recommended version. Check this link: https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce. The reason why this isn't working can be the deprecated dependencies.

Comment: yes i want to use depreceted version

Comment: Then you should try downgrading the webpack version.

Comment: to which version

Comment: it think there is a proptypes issue